# While comparing two excels data integrity is failed even though required data is present using java apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using java with Apache poi for comparing two excel sheets. The value in DB excel is 21080297 and value from another excel is also 21080297 . But when we compare it shows like this Data do not Match - Data from DB: ' 21080297 ' Data from report: ' 2 '. Can anyone help me how to resolve this?

Comment: *How* are you comparing those values? Can you show some code?

Comment: Did you allow for a small difference as floating point is imprecise? Formats might be misleading.

Comment: The DataFormatter class in POI can be used to confirm raw double precision numbers stored in Excel files to the form they are displayed as in the workbook - http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#formatCellValue-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.